# Variations in chocolate bar breaking algorithm in recursive manner

Tags: algorithm, recursion

We are given a chocolate bar with m  n squares of chocolate, and our task is to divide it
into mn individual squares. We are only allowed to split one piece of chocolate at a time
using a vertical or a horizontal break.
How to make variations or break the bar  in this methods so that it will not give optimal solution..

Comment: Have you made any attempt at this?  Include code.  Also please edit for clarity.  You're likely to get flagged.

Comment: What kind of optimality are you referring to? minimizing number of divisions? (if so, *any* breaking strategy will have exactly m*n-1 steps)

Comment: @EyalSchneider Unless you are able to break multiple pieces in half at the same time, kind of like ripping a paper in half then putting it over it's own half then ripping it in half again.

Comment: @JohnOdom: yes, that would make the optimal number of steps to be logarithmic. However, the OP specifically says "We are only allowed to split one piece of chocolate at a time".

Comment: Are you asking for a way to break them that is NOT optimal? Clarification on the question would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well since only one bar can be broken at a time every break increases the number of the pieces by one. So mn-1 breaks are needed to go from m n to mn. Therefore when you don't have any breaks you only have one piece, then after one break you have two, after two breaks you have three pieces and so on.